# Twilio Client: error 31104 - Invalid bridge token

Tags: javascript, salesforce, twilio

We've an app that uses Twilio Client to implement a C2C system on a browser.

It works OK on many different installations, but we're having problems with one subscriber.

The normal scenario would be:

1. User clicks on the phone to dial
2. User receives a call on his Twilio client, and then a call is initiated to the phone to dial
3. Called party answers and both persons talk

But on this problematic case, something weird is happening on the user side:

Instead of one, two calls are received by the user's Twilio client. When receiving the second one, we get an error on the JS console saying "Call has already been accepted", and we're given an error code of 31104, which (according to Twilio) means "Invalid bridge token". And the call is finished on the Twilio Client side.

Looking at the Twilio logs I see that only one call is initiated to the user's Twilio Client, but on the browser we're seeing this strange behavior that is blocking the usage of Twilio Client (as the second call to the Twilio Client triggers an error and finishes the first call).

I wasn't able to find further information around this 31104 error. Does anyone out there have faced this issue before? Or a similar issue while using Twilio Client?